# Splitting a large text file into multiple smaller file by paragraph

Tags: bash, shell

I have a large .txt file that contains sentences and paragraphs, separated by a blank lines.

I would like to split this file (at each blank line) into multiple individual files.

Is there a way to do this using split in terminal? For example, somehow splitting by "\n\n"?

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v RS= '{ print > FILENAME "." FNR }' file
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.